# Unable to configure mysql database, after cloud sql proxy setup

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Configured cloud sql proxy, as per this link
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-admin-proxy

Enabled the Cloud SQL Admin API. while connecting to mysql with following command getting below error

```
[prudvee143@centos-2 ~]$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
Enter password: 
2018/12/11 02:21:34 New connection for "bookshelfs-221608:us-central1:test"
2018/12/11 02:21:34 couldn't connect to "bookshelfs-221608:us-central1:test": ensure that the account has access to "bookshelfs-221608:us-central1:test" (and make sure there's no typo in that name). Error during createEphemeral for bookshelfs-221608:us-central1:test: googleapi: Error 403: Access Not Configured. Cloud SQL Admin API has not been used in project 317520816688 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin.googleapis.com/overview?project=317520816688 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry., accessNotConfigured
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

Commands used for this:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy
chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy

[prudvee143@centos-2 ~]$ 2018/12/11 02:14:55 failed to setup file descriptor limits: failed to set rlimit {&{8500 4096}} for max file descriptors: invalid argument
2018/12/11 02:14:55 using credential file for authentication; email=sql-651@bookshelfs-221608.iam.gserviceaccount.com
2018/12/11 02:14:55 Listening on 127.0.0.1:3306 for bookshelfs-221608:us-central1:test
2018/12/11 02:14:55 Ready for new connections
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to enable the `Cloud SQL API`.

You can enable the API using the Google Cloud Console:

1. Go to `APIs & Services`
2. Go to `Library`
3. Enter `SQL` in the `Search for APIs & Services`
4. Select `Cloud SQL Admin API`
5. Click `Enable`.

You will also need to enable `Cloud SQL`. Repeat the above steps.

Comment: Enabled both, still got `failed to setup file descriptor limits: failed to set rlimit {&{8500 4096}} for max file descriptors: invalid argument` error

Comment: @Devy - Create a new question and include details on your configuration. Make sure that billing is enabled and working.

Comment: @NicolaAmadio I don't remember. It was a long time ago and I believe I switched from MySQL to PostgreSQL instead after that.